# " Magic number did not match " error message while trying to genertae signed apk

Tags: android

In android studio, i am getting this error message when i click on generate signed apk. Its saying there is an exception in exception in Plugin Android Support . It generates this stacktrace

```
Magic number did not match
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Magic number did not match
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxSerializerKt.readKdbxHeader(KdbxSerializer.kt:146)
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxSerializer.createUnencryptedInputStream(KdbxSerializer.kt:61)
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxStreamFormat.load(kdbx.kt:55)
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxKt.loadKdbx(kdbx.kt:36)
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.KeePassCredentialStore.<init>(KeePassCredentialStore.kt:82)
    at com.intellij.credentialStore.KeePassCredentialStore.<init>(KeePassCredentialStore.kt:44)
    at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.impl.PasswordSafeImplKt.computeProvider(PasswordSafeImpl.kt:38)
    at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.impl.PasswordSafeImpl.<init>(PasswordSafeImpl.kt:46)
    at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.impl.PasswordSafeImpl.<init>(PasswordSafeImpl.kt)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:103)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ServiceManagerImpl.java:228)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:239)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:206)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.doGetService(ServiceManager.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:38)
    at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.PasswordSafe.getInstance(PasswordSafe.java:28)
    at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.KeystoreStep.<init>(KeystoreStep.java:71)
    at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard.<init>(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:110)
    at org.jetbrains.android.actions.GenerateSignedApkAction.actionPerformed(GenerateSignedApkAction.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:215)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:232)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:309)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:929)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:136)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:299)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:109)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:118)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:116)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6541)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:827)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:651)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:365)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

It builds when I use instant run or when I Build APK(s) but doesnt just work for genenrate signed apks.Kindly help me out

Comment: You might need to reinstall studio,  happens sometime if update not happened properly and complete.

Comment: I just uinstalled and reinstalled it back and it doesnt still work

Comment: Did u clear all cache  of studio?  Reinstall won't clear sometime cache stays

Comment: I went to Files>invalidate cache/restart,didnt work then I uninstalled it and reinstalled it back. Or is there some other other way I could clear the cache?

Comment: Could u see how to clear gradle cache,  it may help

Comment: it says the problem is with the android support plugin, have any idea how i can uninstall and install it back

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165296/discussion-between-a-lang-and-lib4).